# Salesforce Developer Workbench Hosted Version OAuth Error - Remote Access Authorization Error

Tags: oauth2, remote-access, workbench

On attempting to log in to the hosted Workbench site https://workbench.developerforce.com with my force.com credentials, I am constantly getting an error that seems to be OAuth flow related. But I am unable to determine if the error is due to Salesforce not providing appropriate token to the Workbench or some other error.

Remote Access Authorization Error

There was a problem in setting up your remote access

The redirected URL is  https://na15.salesforce.com/setup/secur/RemoteAccessErrorPage.apexp?oauth_error_code=1800&display=popup

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not going to say I'm solving it (far from that) but it seems to be related to recently created (na15) orgs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509377/salesforce-api-oauth-authorization-error-1800 & http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23344/salesforce-login-issues & if anybody wants to reference the Support Case: #08656038

Comment: Looking into this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue with OAuth on NA15, but should be resolved now. I tested with Workbench with a brand new NA15 org and its working as expected.

Comment: Just checked, it indeed works :) Any chance for a confession what was wrong? ;)

Comment: This defect seems to have regressed.  I have a na15 developer org (created 5/3/2013) that encounters this problem on both workbench and aside.io.

Comment: I have same issue some one can help me :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839836/salesforce-android-app-remote-access-application-authorization