# Help link is not working

Tags: help

I want to log a case in salesforce but when I click on Help link then it does nothing and returns following URL https://help.salesforce.com/hthome?err=1. Whenever I hit Create Case icon I am redirect to below page

[image]

What could be possible wrong? Any idea?

Comment: Seems to be specific to you... even if I enter that URL I get to the help. What HTTP code do you get?

Comment: @LaceySnr Please see the updated question. I am not getting any HTTP error but I am redirected home page again and over again.

Comment: Yup I see that — looks like something is broken! I've just sent them a message to say so.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible they screwed up OAuth flows again. I've seen it happening in the past. Just out of curiosity, can you check if the https://workbench.developerforce.com works for you?

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509377/salesforce-api-oauth-authorization-error-1800
2. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23344/salesforce-login-issues (in the chat transcript you can see that https://help.salesforce.com/hthome?err=1 is mentioned)
3. [Salesforce Developer Workbench Hosted Version OAuth Error - Remote Access Authorization Error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7663/salesforce-developer-workbench-hosted-version-oauth-error-remote-access-author)

Try poking @ryanbrainard for help or maybe you can use credentials from another org to raise a Case with support?

Answer (score 1):

Case creation will only work on production orgs. Make sure you not in a developer or sandbox.