# Unable to log salesforce support case from developer edition

Tags: support, developer-edition

I want to log a case in my developer edition.
When I click on Contact Support from this URL:
https://help.salesforce.com/HTUnauthContactSupport
I can see an Open a Case icon.
On clicking it I get taken to salesforce login page and after entering credentials it shows empty  page with below url
https://help.salesforce.com/hthome?err=1

Anyone faced same issue ?

Comment: @BaskaranS were you able to login a case

Comment: No, sf.dev. So i left the issue there as i did not find a solution a few months ago. Bob buzzard pointed out earlier that there is an issue in submitting the case in free dev editions.

Comment: Done. Please check.

Comment: Check this similar question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11553/help-link-is-not-working & http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7663/salesforce-developer-workbench-hosted-version-oauth-error-remote-access-author (I'm not saying it's a duplicate but looks quite similar to me)

Comment: Looking around the web, I see many reports of same behavior with DE orgs.  This raises the question, how do we request org changes (e.g., enabling Multi-currency) which can only be done by raising a support ticket?  Has anyone done this successfully?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this? @sfdc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From free developer edition you can not create a case. You can call basic support and log a case via phone.

You can create a case on production environment and in sandbox. I had a talk with premier support and get the confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce does not provide technical support for Developer Editions. Please
See https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=overview_de.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

It has been a problem with Developer edition (free). Unfortunately the developer editions which created recently had this type of issues. Do not know whether salesforce provided some other way to raise a ticket. I too need some expert advice who may give better directions. Might be you can try to mention your org id and send an email to saleforce support directly from your personal mail id.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I have a Salesforce partner account. We don't actually have anything listed in the App Exchange but went through the process to become a partner and now have access to a special portal that allows us to raise tickets. The portal is below:

https://sites.secure.force.com/partners/PP2PartnerLoginPage?

You can register as a partner here: https://partnersignup.salesforce.com/

I've had good success opening tickets with them for things like raising API call limits, strange bugs, etc.