# How to open a ticket?

Tags: customer-portal, help

How to open a ticket in salesforce to get personalized support?

this web https://help.salesforce.com has an option called "Open a Case". But, despite I'm authenticated, it gets me to https://help.salesforce.com/hthome?err=1

So I'm not able to open a case

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you opening ticket from developer edition.I recently faced same [issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34186/unable-to-log-salesforce-support-case-from-developer-edition).You need to open ticket with your salesforce partner account.